# Which type of Rails model association should I use in this situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

I have two models/tables in my Rails application: discussions and comments. Each discussion `has_many` comments, and each comment `belongs_to` a discussion. My discussions table also includes a `first_comment_id` column and `last_comment_id` column for convenience and speed. I want to be able to call `discussion.last_comment` for the last comment model, but the following (in my discussion model) isn't working to make this happen:

```
has_one :first_comment, :class_name => "Comment"
has_one :last_comment, :class_name => "Comment"
```

When I call `discussion.last_comment`, the following SQL is run:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE (`comments`.discussion_id = 1) LIMIT 1
```

It's using the `discussions.id` column to join against `comments.discussion_id`, when I want it to join `discussions.last_comment_id` against `comments.id`.

Am I using the wrong type of association here? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a `belongs_to`, rather than a `has_one`.

The naming might be odd, but the difference between the two is really just about which of the tables holds the foreign key column.